# Clone <div> with all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have this div (representing a location room):

```
<div class="card transition">
    <h2 class="transition1"></h2>
    <p class="hovering"></p>
    <div class="cta-container transition"><a href="#" class="cta">Open room</a></div>
    <div class="card_circle transition"></div>
</div>
```

Also I'm doing an AJAX request in order to get the number of location rooms. For example if I have 9 location rooms, I want to dinamically generate 9 div, for each room, containing the same elements as the div above.

I've tried this so far (using an "add" button) to see if I can clone the div, but without success:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        $(div).addClass("cta-container transition").html($('.cta-container transition').clone());
        $(".card transition").append(div);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.cta-container transition')` this should be `$('.cta-container.transition')`

Comment: Your logic looks fine (although you can just do `$('<div />').addClass(...` instead of `document.createElement()`), I would guess the problem is in your last selector: `$("#card transition")`. There is no `<transition>` element - I presume you're missing a `#` or `.` prefix

Comment: just use `.html()` instead of `.clone()`

Comment: um native javascript's `node.cloneNode(true)` can deep clone a node, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to clone a div and its whole children in native:

```
var myDiv=document.getElmentById("myDiv").cloneNode(true);
```

Then you can do:

```
yourElement.appendChild(myDiv);
```